# How to get the database backup into a csv file or .sql file without using runtime commands from java

Tags: java

My require ment is i need to get the database tables data into a single csv file or .sql file without using any mysqldump commands in java

Comment: Why is that a requirement? mysqldump is certainly the most efficient way. Otherwise you have to write JDBC queries over every table in the DB, and manually encode the .CSV/.SQL output yourself. That seems like a waste of time when the ability to do this is already provided for you.

Comment: thanks normalocity.i have a doubt what happens if i dont have permissions to run the commands.

Comment: You still have to worry about permissions to read the DB tables through your JDBC connection. Maybe I'm missing something, but Java isn't going to let you get past permissions issues. Good luck in your search.

Comment: Hi normalocity,my problem is if i use mysqldump i should have previlizes to run that command and if the mysql server is running in remote machine it should give permissions to access remotely,we can't ask client all this things to do,so without doing all this things can u suggest me any option,thanks in advance

Comment: See my project which can generate CSV files for Database Tables https://github.com/overtomanu/Database7.git

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fetch data (select * from table) than create a csv or sql file. 
For csv file, append ',' between fields and append '\n' at end of line
For sql file, append constant prefix like 'insert into table (', and other string values similar to csv.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) supports CSV files. It may help with this.